# Определение города зашедшего на сайт

Tags: php

Есть ли способ определить, из какого города зашел человек на сайт? (Ну и результат засунуть в переменную на php, скажем, `$user_gorod`.)

Comment: повтор вопроса [Определение ip адреса](http://hashcode.ru/questions/90759/%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-ip-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function get_city_quest($ip) {
    $data = '<ipquery><fields><all/></fields><ip-list><ip>' . $ip . '</ip></ip-list></ipquery>';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://194.85.91.253:8090/geo/geo.html");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $xml = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ( substr_count($xml, 'Not found') )
        return false;
    $city = substr(substr($xml, strpos($xml, '<city>'), strpos(substr($xml, strpos($xml, '<city>')), '</city>')), 6);
    return iconv('Windows-1251', 'UTF-8', $city);
}
```

Ровняйте сами.

Comment: эм... дописал естественно

    get_city_quest($ip);

ругается на

    $ch = curl_init();

Comment: Установите curl.

Answer (score 1):

GeoIP Вам в помощь, одно плохо, что нормальные базы платные, но если поискать...