# Как узнать город из которого вошел пользователь php

Tags: php

Есть сайт. Мне нужно увидеть в каком городе пользователь, возможно ли?

Comment: Получить его ip, и пробить по любому сервису.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

был похожий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/100013/php-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82).